# Java / Android activity & database close() issue

Tags: java, android, database, nullpointerexception

I have a problem in my android/java code. I am simply getting the errors when I switch from one activity to the other. The problem I am sure is the database. The main errors in the stack trace is an activity null pointer and a database not explicitly being closed. Can anyone offer me some help regarding this issue?

Is anyone familiar with the error traces below?

The thing is, I have 2 ways to get to the page I want to get too. Going through the shortcut way, the next button gives me the error when I first load the app. But when I go through edit, get to my desired page and come back. The first 'next' then works. It's so annoying!

This is the trace in logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.sec/com.android.sec.TabLayoutActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.sec/com.android.sec.RoomOverview}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-15 20:37:05.333: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.sec/com.android.sec.RoomOverview}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2503)
at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:651)
at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:323)
at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:213)
at com.android.sec.TabLayoutActivity.onCreate(TabLayoutActivity.java:30)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
... 11 more
E/AndroidRuntime(568): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.sec.RoomOverview.onCreate(RoomOverview.java:106)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
E/AndroidRuntime(568):  ... 20 more
```

Here is the class that is throwing the errors:

```
package com.android.sec;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RoomOverview extends Activity {

    public String value = CreateClient.getName();
    public String status = CreateRoom.getStatus();
    private ListView lvItem;
    private ArrayList<String> itemArrey;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> itemAdapter;
    public Cursor c, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6;
    SQLiteDatabase sampleDB;
    public static String selectedItem;
    ImageButton edit, delete;
    final Context context = this;
    public String typeToDelete;
    public static String getID[];

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.roomoverview);

        edit = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.editButton);
        edit.setEnabled(false);
        edit.setAlpha(127);

        delete = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
        delete.setEnabled(false);
        delete.setAlpha(127);

        lvItem = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lvItem.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        itemArrey = new ArrayList<String>();
        itemArrey.clear();

        itemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.single_item,itemArrey);
        lvItem.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

        if(value == "Retrieve"){

            sampleDB = getBaseContext().openOrCreateDatabase(ClientList.retrievedClient+".db", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        } 
        else if (value == "Create"){

            sampleDB = getBaseContext().openOrCreateDatabase(CreateClient.createdClient+".db", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        }


        if(status == "Edit"){

            TextView roomName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.roomName);
            roomName.append(EditRoom.possiblyEditedRoom);
            c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_plant WHERE r_id =?", new String[] {RoomList.r_id});   
            c2 = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_windowData WHERE r_id =?", new String[] {RoomList.r_id}); 
            c3 = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_itData WHERE r_id =?", new String[] {RoomList.r_id}); 
            c4 = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_otherData WHERE r_id =?", new String[] {RoomList.r_id});  
            c5 = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_heatingData WHERE r_id =?", new String[] {RoomList.r_id});    
            c6 = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_lightingData WHERE r_id =?", new String[] {RoomList.r_id});   
        } 
        else if (status == "Create"){

            TextView roomName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.roomName);
            roomName.append(CreateRoom.selectedRoom);
            c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_plant WHERE r_id =?", new String[] {CreateRoom.r_id}); 
            c2 = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_windowData WHERE r_id =?", new String[] {CreateRoom.r_id});
            c3 = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_itData WHERE r_id =?", new String[] {CreateRoom.r_id});   
            c4 = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_otherData WHERE r_id =?", new String[] {CreateRoom.r_id});    
            c5 = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_heatingData WHERE r_id =?", new String[] {CreateRoom.r_id});
            c6 = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_lightingData WHERE r_id =?", new String[] {CreateRoom.r_id});     
        }

        itemArrey.add("---------- Plant ----------");
        if (c != null ) {
            if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {

                    String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("p_id"));
                    String plantName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("itemName"));
                    String plantType = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("itemType"));
                    itemArrey.add("Plant Name: "+plantName+"\n"+"Type: "+plantType+"\n"+"ID: #"+id);

                }while (c.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        c.close();

Multiple of the above i.e. c2, c3, c4 etc. etc. - saves reading 

        lvItem.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text

                selectedItem = (String) ((TextView) view).getText();
                if(selectedItem.contains("----------")){}

                else {
                    edit.setEnabled(true);
                    edit.setAlpha(255);
                    delete.setEnabled(true);
                    delete.setAlpha(255);

                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "item: "+selectedItem+" child: "+parent.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                for(int a = 0; a < parent.getChildCount(); a++)
                {
                    parent.getChildAt(a).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                } 

                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#97C361"));

                }
            }
        });

        edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(selectedItem.contains("----------")){}

                else {

                sampleDB.close();

                if(selectedItem.startsWith("Plant Name:")){
                    typeToDelete = "P";
                } 
                else if (selectedItem.startsWith("Type:")){
                    typeToDelete = "W";
                } 
                else if (selectedItem.startsWith("PC Quantity:")){
                    typeToDelete = "I";
                } 
                else if (selectedItem.startsWith("Other Name:")){
                    typeToDelete = "O";
                } 
                else if (selectedItem.startsWith("Heating Type:")){
                    typeToDelete = "H";
                } 
                else if (selectedItem.startsWith("Lighting Type:")){
                    typeToDelete = "L";
                } 

                getID = selectedItem.split("#");

                if(typeToDelete == "P"){

                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(RoomOverview.this, EditPlant.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent2, 0);

                } 
                else if (typeToDelete == "W"){

                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(RoomOverview.this, EditWindows.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent2, 0);

                } 
                else if (typeToDelete == "I"){

                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(RoomOverview.this, EditIT.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent2, 0);

                } 
                else if (typeToDelete == "O"){

                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(RoomOverview.this, EditOther.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent2, 0);

                } 
                else if (typeToDelete == "H"){

                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(RoomOverview.this, EditHeating.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent2, 0);

                } 
                else if (typeToDelete == "L"){

                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(RoomOverview.this, EditLighting.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent2, 0);

                    }
                }
            }
        });

        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(selectedItem.contains("----------")){}

                else {

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Delete:");

                alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure?").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        //delete building

                        if(selectedItem.startsWith("Plant Name:")){
                            typeToDelete = "P";
                        } 
                        else if (selectedItem.startsWith("Type:")){
                            typeToDelete = "W";
                        } 
                        else if (selectedItem.startsWith("PC Quantity:")){
                            typeToDelete = "I";
                        } 
                        else if (selectedItem.startsWith("Other Name:")){
                            typeToDelete = "O";
                        } 
                        else if (selectedItem.startsWith("Heating Type:")){
                            typeToDelete = "H";
                        } 
                        else if (selectedItem.startsWith("Lighting Type:")){
                            typeToDelete = "L";
                        } 

                        String getID[] = selectedItem.split("#");

                        if(typeToDelete == "P"){
                            sampleDB.delete("tbl_plant", "p_id =?", new String[] {getID[1]});  
                        } 
                        else if (typeToDelete == "W"){
                            sampleDB.delete("tbl_windowData", "w_id =?", new String[] {getID[1]});  
                        } 
                        else if (typeToDelete == "I"){
                            sampleDB.delete("tbl_itData", "i_id =?", new String[] {getID[1]});  
                        } 
                        else if (typeToDelete == "O"){
                            sampleDB.delete("tbl_otherData", "o_id =?", new String[] {getID[1]});  
                        } 
                        else if (typeToDelete == "H"){
                            sampleDB.delete("tbl_heatingData", "h_id =?", new String[] {getID[1]});  
                        } 
                        else if (typeToDelete == "L"){
                            sampleDB.delete("tbl_lightingData", "l_id =?", new String[] {getID[1]});  
                        }

                        sampleDB.close();

                        Intent intent2 = new Intent(RoomOverview.this, TabLayoutActivity.class);
                        startActivityForResult(intent2, 0);     
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        //do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
            }});      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all don't use ...

```
if (value == "Retrieve") { ...

if (value == "Create") { ...

if (status == "Edit") { ...
```

... because that doesn't work in Java. Use ...

```
if ("Retrieve".equals(value)) { ...

if ("Create".equals(value)) { ...

if ("Edit".equals(status)) { ...
```

... instead. As a consequence your cursor `c` will most likely be `null`. That wouldn't be a problem, if you had put the `c.close()` inside of your `if` statement. So secondly move your `close()` method call inside the `if` statement:

```
if (c != null ) {
    if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
           ...

        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close(); // move to here
}
// here, close() is outside of the if causing a NPE if c is null
```

Even, if that might not fix everything - this is at least a start and I hope it helps ;)

Cheers!

Comment: Very helpful, I took over some guys code, reverse engineering the problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: Your welcome. Closing cursor variables that are actually `null` as well as unclosed cursors (often due to overseen conditions) are in many cases the root cause for database issues.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make sure to close your cursors and dbHelper objects after use.
i.e. cursor.close() or dbHelper.close()...etc.

In addition, I would recommend you use a class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper.  Then you can use that helper to get a reference to a SQLiteDatabase,

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
//db.query(....)
//db.select(....)
etc...
```

There are tons of tutorials about this.

Comment: I have made sure I close each cursor using cursor.close() but I still get that error message in the trace! Any other reason it might say that?

Comment: See main question, i've added the source code frmo the problematic class

Comment: Updated my answer a bit.  using the dbHelper is a better way to manage because you don't have to worry about closing everything.

Comment: so does this help to close cursors too?

Answer (score 1):

The exception is originating from line 106, attempting to close a cursor which is null. Either place a check or move the call to close the cursor in to the preceding check for (c != null).

Comment: so you do not have to close the cursor, if it is null?

Comment: Well it's not actually the point. That just happens to be where the exception is being raised. You should try to manage resources and release them when they're no longer needed. If this exception occurs only when switching between activities it is because the state of your activity is not being properly managed. For example the fields 'value' and 'state' are not guaranteed to be retained when switching back to your activity. Best to save state when switching activities. Check out this link on Android.com, http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html.

Comment: Yeah someone else recommended that to me, how hard is it to implement?

Comment: It's super easy to implement actually. All it requires is overriding onStop and OnStart at the most and for retaining state you'll need to override onSavedInstanceState and/or onRestoreInstanceState. Googling any of this will give you oodles of examples. Check out this link http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html.